# Un-ordered 2 string hash function that always produces the same hash

Tags: mongodb, algorithm, go, math, hash

I'm trying to build a travel application that can check for prices between destination A to B, I have a table that stores the data in the terms of `from` and `to` something like

```
CREATE TABLE PRICES {
   from varchar,
   to varchar
   price
```

The thing is, If `from` = `A` and `to` = `B` if I try to search for the price form `B` -> `A` I get no result. i.e `SELECT * from prices where from = 'B' AND to = 'A'` of course I can fix this by doing a query like `SELECT * from prices where from = 'A' And To = 'B' OR from = 'B' and 'To' = 'A'`

Is there a way I can create a hash such that I'll not need to do this `OR` query but rather, I'll just do something like `SELECT * from prices where hash = 'C'` in this case, `C` will be a value such that `hash(a, b) = c = hash(b,a)` then I can store the has `c` in the table and I won't need to do the `OR` query.

I'm using Go btw if that helps but you can come up with the hash function in any language/pseudocode.

Thanks

Comment: Impose an order on the values: `a := from; b := to; if a > b { b, a = a, b }; hash := fmt.Sprintf("%s\t%s", a, b)`

Comment: You're making the assumption that the price to go from A to B is the same as the price to go from B to A. That's unlikely to be universally true. I certainly wouldn't want to build that assumption into the code.

Comment: @JimMischel not only is it not “universally true” it is very common for it not to be. Very often you’ll see flights back from holiday destinations at the beginning of holidays that are much cheaper than the outbound flights for example.

Comment: @Fogmeister Yeah, I often tend to under-state things.

Comment: @JimMischel It's not created to flight prices. It's more like public transport application and indeed prices from A -> B are always the same as prices from B -> A withing a given time range.

Comment: @CeriseLimón Thanks I think that algorithm will work. At times simple things are not so obvious.

Comment: It's true *now*. In my experience, those kinds of things often change. A year or three from now somebody will come up with the bright idea of charging more to get from A to B than from B to A. And they won't think about your travel app, even if you're writing the travel app for the entity that sets the prices. The first you'll hear about the change is when your app stops working.

Answer (score 0):

Sort the strings, concatenate with a delimiter and return the result.

```
func abOrBa(a, b string) string {
    if a > b {
       a, b = b, a
    }
    return fmt.Sprintf("%s\t%s", a, b)
}
```

[Run it on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/oWXZWfnKjPs).

Cost may not be [symmetric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_relation) as noted in the question comments. If so, there may be no value in this approach.